# permanent 301 redirect in Tomcat 5.5

Tags: http, tomcat

Is it possible to do 301 redirect with Tomcat 5.5 running standalone, not behind IIS/Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to set this up as easily as you're able to with Apache. The closest thing would be to make a servlet or jsp to handle the redirect and then map it to the URL you want to redirect from. In the servlet or jsp it would do something like:

```
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.example.com/redirect-to-here.html" );
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect entire folder to new location you need both a JSP and configuration to call this jsp upon 404.

In `index.jsp` you need to modify your redirect behavior. Below code would redirect from `OldApp` folder to `NewApp` folder on the same server.

index.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>301 Moved</title>
</head>
<%@ page import="org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil" %>
<%
    // get the requested URI
    //String requestedLocation = request.getRequestURI();
    // original request
    String requestedLocation = RequestUtil.filter((String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri"));
    // rewrite to new location
    String newLocation = requestedLocation.replaceAll("^/OldApp", "/NewApp");
    // add query string
    String query = request.getQueryString();
    if (!query.isEmpty()) {
        newLocation = newLocation + '?' + query;
    }

    // 301 - permanent redirect
    response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    response.setHeader("Location", newLocation);
%>
<body>
    &rarr; <a href="<%=newLocation%>"><%=newLocation%></a>
</body>
</html>
```

WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```