# Two URLs pointed at same Tomcat instance, have one redirect to the other

Tags: tomcat, ssl, redirect

My setup is like this (unfortunate as it may be).

Two domains point to the same server:
    app.foo.com
    app.bar.com

Two Tomcat instances run on this server, one on port 80, the other on port 443.

The problem is with the secured app on port 443.  I have a SSL certificate installed for app.foo.com, so it works just fine.  The problem is when I go to https://app.bar.com I get the big "not secure" warnings from the browser (as expected).  Is there a way in Tomcat configuration files to have traffic to https://app.bar.com redirect to https://app.foo.com?

Comment: Something like [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770453)? I think this might be the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3761997), if your Tomcat instance isn't behind a web server like Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are aware of how to redirect to the other host in tomcat reading e.g. the Host-Header and sending an 301 or 302 response pointing to the other url. But I think the real question is, if it is possible WITHOUT showing the invalid SSL Warning: This isn't possible because the initial request to https://app.bar.com will only get to your server, if the user manually accepts the invalid certificate.

Answer (score 0):

When requesting https://app.bar.com, no client will ever connect to port 80... they'll always contact port 443. That means if `foo.com` is being hosted on port 443, you'll always get (a) `foo.com`'s certificate and (b) presumably, the `foo.com` application when using HTTPS.

Is there a particular reason to use different ports for these two applications? Why not have:

- https://www.foo.com/foo - app called foo
- https://www.foo.com/bar - app called bar

It's trivial to set things up such that the above URLs work, but also these as well:

- https://www.bar.com/foo - app called foo
- https://www.bar.com/bar - app called bar

If you want to have `foo.com` always abd only serve app `foo` and `bar.com` always serve app `bar` (both on the context `ROOT` aka `/`), then you'll need to choose one of the following strategies:

**Strategy 1 : smarter certificates**

Obtain a certificate which has both `www.foo.com` and `www.bar.com` as [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name)s on the certificate.

This will allow the client to connect without complaint. The client will send the hostname to the server and Tomcat will choose the proper application based upon the hostname.

**Strategy 2: smarter configuration**

Configure name-based virtual hosting (which you certainly already have) with name-based certificate-selection.

1. Configure two separate virtual hosts (`<Host>` in `conf/server.xml`)

   1. `foo.com`
   2. `bar.com`
2. Configure virtual-server-based certificates (requires at least Tomcat 8.5)

   1. Using `<SSLHostConfig>` as a child element of your `<Connector>`
   2. One for each of `foo.com` and `bar.com`